# "based on" vs. "according to"

Tags: word-choice, difference

I wrote :

> For each rule, some refinements are made to the *exData* (according to / based on) its *extraction* *command* and subsequently the output structure is modified **accordingly**.

Which of *according to* and *based on* suits more to this sentence? are they always interchangeable?

Also did I use **accordingly** correctly?

Comment: Yes, your usage is correct. ***Accordingly***: has two main usages - 1) -  ***in a way that is appropriate to the particular circumstances***.
*‘we have to discover what his plans are and act accordingly*’

2) (sentence adverb) ***as a result; therefore***.
*‘there was no breach of the rules; accordingly, there will be no disciplinary inquiry*’- https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/accordingly

Comment: **Based on** generally does not refer directly to a person, while **according to** can refer either to a person or an object. _According to Joe, we will win the game. His prediction is based on our lead._

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference between the two, but it doesn't matter much.

> ... according to its extraction command ...

This may mean that the extraction command can somehow be viewed as the "author" of a rule or advice for best practice, which somehow may be *implied*.

> ... based on its extraction command ...

This may mean that whatever rules apply are *inferred* by the person writing the document.

The line is blurry, however, and if such nuances are lost on you or your audience, either term will suffice to get your meaning across.